# Python inheritance type error, cannot extend Enum class

Tags: python, oop, enums

I am writing code for a child's bank account moderator, I created a `User` class with the details of the child, as well as a `UserType` class which `User` will inherit from. The `UserType` class inherits from the base `Enum` class, I set the `UserType` class to contain the types of users a parent can select when registering, each type of user will be assigned an int value.

In the initializer for the `User`, I tried making it so `self._user_type = user_type.user_types.auto` would assign the type of user based on the int value entered when someone is registering their child and entering their details from a menu selection in the main method.

```
class User(UserType):
    child_id = 0

    def __init__(self, child_name, child_age, user_type, bank_account_number, bank_name, bank_balance, budget):
        self._child_name = child_name
        self._child_age = child_age
        self._user_type = user_type.user_types.auto
        self._bank_account_number = bank_account_number
        self._bank_name = bank_name
        self._bank_balance = bank_balance
        self._budget = budget
        _child_id = User.id_counter()
```

When I try to instantiate a user object, `user1 = user.User("John", 12, 1, 12345, "Coast Capital", 1000, 500)`, I am getting an error Unexpected argument(s) `TypeError: <enum 'User'> cannot extend <enum 'UserType'>`.

```
import enum
from enum import auto

class UserType(enum.Enum):
    THE_ANGEL = auto()
    THE_REBEL = auto()
    THE_TROUBLEMAKER = auto()
```

```
import user

def main():
    print("Welcome to FAM")
    print("Please select from one of the following options: ")
    print("1. Register your child?")
    print("2. Login")
    choice = (int(input("Select between 1 or 2\n")))

    user1 = user.User("John", 12, 1, 12345, "Coast Capital", 1000, 500)
```

Why is it throwing a type error when I try to instantiate the `User` object?

I tried multiple inheritance to get it to work by having the class `class User(UserType, enum.Enum):`.

Comment: It's not clear why `User` is inheriting from `UserType` in the first place. Enum classes are barely classes in the usual sense. `UserType` is a collection of constants; it's not modeling something that `User` then tries to refine or specialize in some way.

Comment: Instances of `User` should have a `UserType`-valued *attribute* instead.

Comment: @chepner my thought process was that when someone is registering their child, i would extract the input and place it into an object user1 = (...), that way when you enter the information, the int value entered by the parent would determine what type of user account they want for their child, which is the enum class i made for the types of users. If i place it in an attribute, I would need helper methods to determine the user type the parent wants?

Comment: `UserType` defines the types of users; it is not itself *a* type of user, nor would a subclass of `UserType` be a type of user.

Comment: If you have a `User` class, you might subclass *it*, with `class Angel(User): ...`, `class Rebel(User): ...`, `class TroubleMaker(User): ...`, etc to define different kinds of users.

Answer (score 1):

The user class definitely shouldn't try to extend the user type enumeration.

You'll want something like

```
class User:
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        child_name: str,
        child_age: int,
        user_type: UserType,
        bank_account_number: str,
        bank_name: str,
        bank_balance: str,
        budget: int,
    ):
        self._child_name = child_name
        self._child_age = child_age
        self._user_type = user_type
        self._bank_account_number = bank_account_number
        self._bank_name = bank_name
        self._bank_balance = bank_balance
        self._budget = budget
```

-- I added the type annotations for clarity, and made the constructor kwarg-only because that'll avoid a class of bugs where you pass in arguments in the wrong order.

Then you'd instantiate one with

```
user.User(child_name="John", child_age=12, user_type=UserType.THE_ANGEL, ...
```

Comment: thank you! I was not thinking of the arguments in the wrong order. I did not want to hard code the value of the user_type = UserType.THE_ANGEL, because that would be dependent on what input the user enters when they are registering a user, which gets placed into the user.User Object. I am trying to find a way to have it so when the user object gets initialized through input, the UserType is stored based on what the input selection is.

Comment: Sure, you can prompt the user for the user type and just pass it in when instantiating the user. It's not any more hard-coded here than "John" and 12 are.

Comment: I meant that's what i am testing, i just hard coded the values and its throwing a type error because i set the user type to 1 in the object